# How can we disable to mass email functions to prevent overflow of daily limits?

Tags: email

Is there a way to disable the mass email options within Saleforce to allow us to prevent the user community from throwing us over the daily limits?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; this can be configured by profiles and permission sets. If you remove the "Mass Email" permission the users will not be able to use it.

**Update**

Using the old Profile interface, this permission is in the "General User Permissions" block.

In the Enhanced Profile interface it is under "System Permissions".